# Non-Existent View Controller getting viewDidAppear called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller, viewdidappear

I have a navigationController that I reuse for my Splash screen.  Whenever I log out, I reset the navigationController's viewControllers array to just the single Splash screen.  However I'm getting some odd behavior.

Steps:

Splash comes up - modal display, navigationController with single Splash viewController as root
Select "Sign In" - Sign In view pushes on to Nav Controller

Enter info, submit, success, dismiss modal View

Go through the app.... then Logout again

Replace modal navigationController's viewControllers (currently Splash -> Sign In) with a newly made viewController (Splash).

Present Modal ViewController

UNEXPECTED BEHAVIOR **

Original "Sign In" View Controller's viewDidAppear method gets called.

Other than the "Sign In" view controller's viewDidAppear getting called, everything behaves like normal.  The new Splash comes up, I can push a new Sign In on, no problem.  Everything continues as normal.

I have a NSNotificationCenter addObserver in my viewDidAppear, so this extra viewDidAppear getting called is throwing off behaviors in the app else where, which is why I need to figure out where this is coming from and fix it.

Backtrace Paused at erroneous "viewDidAppear"

```
Thread 1, Queue : (null)
0   0x000f1881 in -[KeyboardViewController viewDidAppear:] at /Users/Me/App/Classes/KeyboardViewController.m:69
1   0x00d79fbf in -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] ()
2   0x00d7a2d4 in -[UIViewController __viewDidAppear:] ()
3   0x00d7b8c9 in __64-[UIViewController viewDidMoveToWindow:shouldAppearOrDisappear:]_block_invoke_0 ()
4   0x00d7a730 in -[UIViewController _executeAfterAppearanceBlock] ()
5   0x00cc35ea in _afterCACommitHandler ()
6   0x01dfa9ce in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
7   0x01d91670 in __CFRunLoopDoObservers ()
8   0x01d5d4f6 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
9   0x01d5cdb4 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
10  0x01d5cccb in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
11  0x0261b879 in GSEventRunModal ()
12  0x0261b93e in GSEventRun ()
13  0x00cb2a9b in UIApplicationMain ()
14  0x000028d9 in main ()
```

If I popToRootViewController in the navigationController before dismissing it, this issue goes away.  However, if I wait .5 seconds and dismiss once the navigationController is already dismissed, the issue persists.  Ideally I don't want to popToRootViewController while it's dismissing...

Then when I was calling popToRootViewController before dismissing, the viewDidDisappear method wasn't getting called...  For now, I've got a hack in place that takes a snapshot of the current stack of viewControllers, replaces them, loads the view, then iterates over the stored stack of Controllers, undoing the code that runs in the viewDidAppear method (NSNotification stuff...)

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `viewDidAppear`.  Trigger the bug.  Post the stack trace at the breakpoint.

Comment: Any ideas?  This viewDidAppear getting called multiple times is really  annoying....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this is happening, but I think it would be better to call `popToRootViewController:NO` on the navigation controller to reset it rather than manually modifying it's viewControllers array.

Try that and see if it still has a problem.

Comment: I have tried calling popToRootViewController:NO before calling my setViewControllers call, but I get the same behavior

Comment: Is `viewDidAppear` getting called even if you just `popToRootViewController:NO` and don't set the view controllers?

Comment: Yes, just popToRootViewController (no setViewControllers) still results in viewDidAppear getting called

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure then. It's hard to make any other guesses without more information. Do what Rob said and put a breakpoint in viewDidAppear and post the stack trace.

Comment: And it's always the most recent "Sign In" viewController that was used.  So Splash -> Sign In 1 -> App -> Logout (Sign In 1 viewDidAppear) -> Splash -> Sign In 2 -> App -> Logout (Sign In 2 viewDidAppear)

Answer (score 0):

As you said

> Whenever I log out, I reset the navigationController's viewControllers
>   array to just the single Splash screen.

This indicates that you are setting navigationController's viewControllers again not the NavigationController itself.

It happens because whenever we put new viewcontroller's array in navigation stack, before releasing earlier viewcontroller it calls their view appearance methods.

I had the same problem. I created the navigationController again rather than reusing the old one(I released it).

Thanks,

Comment: The NavigationController that I'm using was set up with some custom attributes in my .xib file, so ideally I'd like to reuse that object for now.  Also, I'm curious why just the viewDidAppear method is getting called (when the view never actually appears) but then viewDidDisappear never gets called.